Using Selenium,a beginner here,I was using system.setProperty to set the path for .exe file from local directory but its giving error
Using Selenium,a beginner here,I was using system.setProperty to set the path for .exe file from local directory but its giving error,although I know now after selenium 4.5 selenium manager does the work to download .exe file internally,but i was just curious and changed my selenium dependency version to 4.0.0,downloaded the chromedriver.exe file from CFT dashboard,and extracted it,gave the path but i am getting a syntax error which i dont know why its throwing the syntax error-"Syntax error on token ")", delete this token",everything seems fine to me,any help would be appreciated,thanks.
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
public class WebDriverBasics {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
           System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\rookie\\Documents\\MyDriver\\chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();    //4.23.0
    //EdgeDriver driver=new EdgeDriver();\
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    String title=driver.getTitle();
    if(title.equalsIgnoreCase("google")) 
    {
        System.out.println("Correct Title....Pass");
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("Incorrect Title....Fail");
    }
    driver.quit();
    }

}
I couldnt get forward due to syntax error
-Syntax error on token ")", delete this token
